# WordPress Code in Launch Configuration

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, sed, aws-cloudformation

I'm having hard time to understand the functionality of the below sed commands and how the operation is performed. I would be glad if anyone explains in detail about the code.

```html
"#!/bin/bash\n",
"cp /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php\n",
"sed -i \"s/'database_name_here'/'",
{
"Ref": "DBName"
},
"'/g\" wp-config.php\n",
"sed -i \"s/'username_here'/'",
{
"Ref": "DBUser"
},
"'/g\" wp-config.php\n",
"sed -i \"s/'password_here'/'",
{
"Ref": "DBPassword"
},
"'/g\" wp-config.php\n",
"sed -i \"s/'localhost'/'",
{
"Fn::GetAtt": [
  "DBInstance", "Endpoint.Address"
 ]
},
"'/g\" wp-config.php\n"
```

Thanks

Comment: What explanation do you expect?

Comment: Regarding the sed commands. I searched in internet but couldn't figure it out.